# Simple Symfony 2 multi-tennant application

Tags: php, symfony

I need help with multi-tennancy in Symfony 2.

Rails example here:
http://samuel.kadolph.com/2010/12/simple-rails-multi-tenancy/

Where to start in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Symfony 2 listener system. Beware though that in PHP this is a design issue and these type of things are not (best to my knowledge) handled by the framework you are using.

We have one instance of an application to run multiple installs (tenants), and allow the users to switch between the ones they have access to.

When the user is defined their default install ID is set, so when the user logs in to the system it takes them to this install. The user can then switch to another install if they have access to it (defined in lookup table in DB).

When the login request is sent, the listener checks to see if the installId is set on the session. If not then the user is loaded and the default installId is set on the session. The install is then supplied to the application via a factory, via the Service Container. The installId set on the session is used to load the current install. This instance of install is used by other services in the Service Container to supply only data related to the current install. When a user switches installs the new installId is set in the session and the user is redirected to the home page. The redirect forces the new installId to be used to load the alternate install the user has switched to.